# How to create options of a select element dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to create options of a select element dynamically via an ajax call. The number of options and their content will vary. This is how it looks prior to the ajax call:

```
 <select name="groupid" style="width:100%;">
<option value="0" selected>(Please select an option)</option>
</select>
```

Here is one of my attempts to create an option element with a dummy value:

```
$("<option></option>", {value: "999"}).appendTo('.select-group');
```

But it adds it outside of select. I also don't know how to set the text within .

Any ideas? I've seen some questions about populating existing select forms with a static number of existing options but not one like this.

Thanks.

Comment: If `'.select-group'` is your `select` element, then it will work, though you probably want to give it some text too: `{value: "999", text: "999"}`.

Comment: read more here - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/add-append-insertoptions-select-options-using-jquery-javascript/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Where's `.select-group`? If you use id of `#groupid` then this should work just fine...

```
$('<option>').val('999').text('999').appendTo('#groupid');
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is the solution..

```
$('#yourSelectBoxId').append(new Option('optionName', 'optionValue'));
```

Answer (score 11):

If I understood correctly, below is what you need,

```
$("<option></option>", 
     {value: "999", text: "Nine Ninety Nine"})
    .appendTo('.select-group');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/JwX4B/)

Provided `.select-group` is the selector for the `<select></select>`

Answer (score 4):

**Here is alternative solution. this worked for me.**

```
$('#yourSelectBoxId').append("<option value='Saab'>Saab</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`$('#chat_list').append(new Option(this.subject, this.key_remote_jid));`