# How to load select options from external files with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic city drop-down selector, where a user selects a country, then a region, then a city. Right now I have two tables in a MySQL database, one with all the regions, and one with all the cities, and I am using jQuery to first load the regions when a user selects a country, then a city when a region is selected.

My site gets quite a bit of traffic, and I am worried this is terribly inefficient... every time someone makes a selection, the database is queried and sometimes hundreds of rows are parsed and returned.

Instead of querying the database, since the list of cities will never change, I want to store each country and region as a separate file, and load them when needed.

For example:
IE.html (Ireland)

```
<option value="0" selected>- Select -</option>
<option value="11287">Connaught</option>
<option value="11288">Leinster</option>
<option value="11289">Munster</option>
<option value="11290">Ulster</option>
```

11290.html (Ulster)

```
<option value="xxxxxxx">Buncrana</option>
<option value="xxxxxxx">Cavan</option>
<option value="xxxxxxx">Letterkenny</option>
<option value="xxxxxxx">Monaghan</option>
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to load these files back into the select menus. There are loads of resources out there about creating options with external files, but I can't find anything about loading plain HTML into the form.

Is this even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135091/jquery-take-value-and-insert-into-dropdown-menu-and-add-url-as-option-value

Comment: I saw that one, but it seems too complicated... the files already are formatted properly.

Comment: Using ajax get the file and append or insert into the selectbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method in the jQuery. See the example below.

```
$( "#dropdowndiv" ).load( "ajax/11290.html" );
```

You can either store the whole `select` there or just the `options`. Depending on what you store in the file use the jQuery selector.

## Note

Having thousands of users won't slow your site down if you have implemented the site correctly. Search the term `High Availability For Database`.

Comment: Thank you! That's probably why I couldn't find this anywhere - because the answer was so obvious.

Comment: Moving data from the database is implementing a site correctly. Thousands of users won't slow a site down, but doing inefficient DB queries will. Countries, regions and cities don't change all that much.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a few arrays in a separate js file that hold the values ie:

`var myCars=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");`

Then dynamically create the options with a for loop (or foreach) in jquery by looking here:

[How to create options of a select element dynamically using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727930/how-to-create-options-of-a-select-element-dynamically-using-jquery)

I would provide more code samples, but I am limited since I am on my phone.